# How to get an array of objects after several ajax calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ajax

In a project, I implement checkbox filters via ajax. In my controller I have an action:

```
def casinos_filters
    providers_from_categories = Provider.joins(:categories).where('categories.id = ?', params[:category_id])
    providers = Casino.joins(:providers).where('providers.id = ?', params[:provider_id])
    providers_from_categories.each do |provider|
      @filtered_casinos = provider.casinos
    end
    casinos_list = []
    casinos_list << @filtered_casinos if params[:category_id]
    casinos_list << providers if params[:provider_id]


    render json: { casinos: casinos_list.uniq }, status: 200
  end
```

As a result, I want the array `casinos_list` include the casinos' objects. Clicking on a `category` checkbox, I get the json. But when I click the next `category` checkbox, the json doesn't have previous results. I think it's due to the initializing an empty array in the action. Is there any way to initialize the array only once, not on every ajax call? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP requests are stateless. You either need to store them in client side (as Javascript models/collections) or on the server side to be able to collect them together.